# Lightning Component not differentiating SF1 Theme and Salesforce Classic user interface theme

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have a lightning component which is displayed in a vf page. There are 2 buttons in the page that I need to hide when the user is in SF1. I have used the UIThemeDisplayed global variables to determine  the current user experience context. However it is not working.

```
    vf page
    =======

 <apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false" 
  applyBodyTag="false" applyHtmlTag="false"  controller="ChatterFeedController">
<apex:includeLightning />
<apex:includeScript value="/lightning/lightning.out.js" />
<apex:stylesheet value="/resource/SLDS/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-
 design-system-vf.css"/>
 <div id="lightning" />

 <script>
 var userContext = "{!$User.UIThemeDisplayed}";
 var groupId = "0F98E0000004UhA";

          $Lightning.use("c:THORannouncementApp", function() {
          $Lightning.createComponent("c:THORAnnouncementlghtcomp",
          {groupattid : groupId,
           userMode : userContext},                            
         "lightning",
         function(cmp) {
        // do some stuff
         });        
         }
        );

 </script>

</apex:page>


    Controller
    ===========
         //Check for SF1 or Desktop
             userModeCheck: function(component, event, helper) {
             var userTheme = component.get("v.userMode");
             console.log("UserTheme-->"+userTheme);
             component.set("v.userMode",userTheme);
            },
```

I am putting an aura if condition to filter out a part of the code in the component only if it is SF1

```
   Component
   =========

   <aura:attribute name="userMode" type="String" /> 


   <aura:if isTrue="{!userMode != 'Theme4t'}">  
      <div class="slds-p-horizontal--small slds-size--1-of-2 slds-medium-size--1-of-6 slds-large-size--5-of-12">
        <div class="slds-grid slds-grid--vertical-stretch">
           <ui:button label="Click here to access THOR"  aura:id="button" press="{!c.gotothor}"/>
           <ui:button label="Click here to access THOR Portal"  aura:id="button" press="{!c.gotothorportal}"/>         
        </div> 
      </div>
 </aura:if>
```

Still, the buttons appear in SF1. Is this the correct way to do it ?

Comment: You can get the user agent or do SOQL on loginHistory and then do it whatever you want.

Comment: @AvijitChakraborty I don't Understand. Can you please elaborate..

Comment: If User is coming from SF1 which means they are using mobile or tablet. var mobileOrTab = (/iphone|ipad|ipod|android|blackberry|mini|windows\sce|palm/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase())); If this is true which mean user is on mobile device. you can check this also https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_loginhistory.htm If you do a SOQL on LoginHistory you can get the value of API and platform and took the decision of accessing from SF1 or not.

Comment: Thanks.. But using the global variable UIThemeDisplayed and using the userAgent or the soql on Login history gives the same result.The problem is how to do afterwards.. I can get the current User Theme from the controller (in classic gives Theme3 , in Lightning gives Theme 4d) However the problem comes when I pass it to an attribute in the component and use the auraif condition. The component is not able to differentiate I believe.

Comment: You should use init to achieve this see here https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_init_handler.htm

Comment: Looks like $User.UIThemeDisplayed is not working correctly at the moment, see this issue https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000EAWGQA4